# Circular Reference : asmx + entity framework + Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asmx

I have a model designed by this way : 
Users => Profiles => modules => treatments

this model is Reverse engineered by Entity Framwork code first ( SQL SERVER DATABASE )

Entities - Mapping ...etc, are in a distinct dll.

Im Using an asmx , that retieves my entities, and returs a list of common parameters to my application :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
[Serializable]
public class WsMaster 
{

    public WsMaster()
    {

    }
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public List<object> GetCommonParameters()
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        try
        {
            CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)Session["UserCulture"];
            User user = CDU.Bll.CduBLL.getUser((int)Session["userId"]);
            CommonParameters CommonParameters = new CommonParameters(user,culture);
            list.Add((object)new CommonLabels(culture));
            list.Add(user);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            HandleException(exp);
        }
        return list;

    }
}
```

In my aspx pages , I referenced this service :

```
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Business/Administration/WsMaster.asmx" />
```

Im calling then the service directly from Javascript :

```
 WsMaster.GetCommonParameters(showCDUPageSuccess, showCDUPageFailure);
```

I got this error

```
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'CDU.Entities.Models.User'.
```

this is because the object user contains a profile , that contains a list of users ...etc

I disabled the lazy Loading for Entity Framework :

```
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

and then want to load on demand :

```
User user = new User();
        using (cduContext db = new cduContext())
        {
            user = (from u in db.Users.Include("Profile")
                    where u.Id==Id
                    select u).FirstOrDefault();

        }
```

The profile Includes his list of users ... , and I got the same error. I solved this by setting the user's list of the profile to null :

```
user.Profile.Users = null;
```

Is there any way to disable the serialisation of this "Users List" in the profile !?
Help Please ...

Comment: I think you should make DTO User objects that do not reference User but instead reference the "User Keys" within the profile. It sounds like you are utilizing your domain objects as DTO objects, this is also a poor design choice in general because you now have coupled your contracts to your domain. WSDLs should be stable, domains should be flexible and adaptable.

Comment: Hi JDPeckham!
thanks for your answer, I'll try with DTO . 
My design is poor , indeed ... any proposition ??

Comment: If you have a .dbml file, have you tried setting your relationships to unidirectional ?